# Entry name 'javax/annotation/CheckReturnValue.java' collided Generate Debug apk

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, annotations

I am using Android Studio 4.0.1. The following error occurs when I try to produce a ***debug version*** of the program. (No problem to produce a **release version**!)

***Create Debug Version***

[image]

ERROR

> Entry name 'javax/annotation/CheckReturnValue.java' collided

[image]

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
//apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ai"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 6
        versionName "0.3.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.dev'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.kailashdabhi:om-recorder:1.1.5'
    implementation 'com.fxn769:musicwave:1.0'
    implementation 'com.tbuonomo.andrui:viewpagerdotsindicator:4.1.2'
//    implementation "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0"

    //firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'
//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.5'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.1'
    implementation 'com.github.amirdew:JSON:v1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'

    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'


    implementation 'com.github.ohoussein.playpauseview:playpauseview:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.nabinbhandari.android:permissions:3.7'

    implementation 'com.job:droidnet:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'

    implementation 'com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview:taptargetview:1.13.0'

}
```

I **cleaned** the project and even **rebuild** it but the problem remains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deleting the existing apk from the debug folder and rebuilding the apk should work.